# Use 1-1 relationship for primary key or clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Consider the tables `T` and `U` below. `T` is the data table, and `U` is a table with *additional* data. Hence, a 1-to-1 relationship where joins are done at the `TID`. In my database, the primary key of table `U` is currently never used.

**Q:** Considering performance, would it be better to replace table `U` with `V` (effectively removing the extra primary key)? Would it make a difference if I added a covering index for these tables?

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    TID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TID ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE U (
    UID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_U_TID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T(TID)
 CONSTRAINT PK_U PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UID ASC)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX U_TID_Index ON U (TID ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE V (
    TID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_V_TID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T(TID)
 CONSTRAINT PK_V PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TID ASC)
)
GO
```

Comment: Why not put `U` as a column in `T` if it's `1:1` relationship?

Comment: Is that really the definition of `V` that you're considering? I'd have expected it to still have a foreign key back to `T` and to not have an `IDENTITY` defined (since I assumed `TID` was going to come from `T`)

Comment: This is a stripped down example. And yes, `TID` comes from `T`. Yes, the foreign key should still be there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I have updated the question. Now it looks more correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the association is indeed 1:1, there is no point in having an extra primary key - all it does is force you to create yet another index, and it's not even clustered. By adding the separate primary key, you've effectivelly doubled the size of the table (presumably, the `TID` index would cover the entire table).

Adding another key/id would only make sense if the relationship weren't 1:1 - the most obvious example of course being a 1:n relationship. However, even in that case, you would usually make a primary key and a clustered index over a pair of IDs - the `TID` *and* the "uniquizer".

A completely separate ID is a good choice when you need to work with the "child" independent of the parent - if you usually query it by its parent, there's little point in having a separate ID.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (
     TID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT PK_T PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TID ASC)
  )

GO

CREATE TABLE V
  (
     TID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_V_TID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES T(TID)
     CONSTRAINT PK_V PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TID ASC)
  )

GO
```

Your second table is not at all required. You can go with two tables table-1 and table-3.

This approach gives better performance than either adding non clustered index or covering index to your table-2.